# NHibernate QueryOver - Date Comparison expression

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Using a NHibernate QueryOver expression, how can I compare against a local variable?

For example:

[DB Table]

```
1 - 01/01/2011
2 - 02/20/2011
3 - 03/09/2011
```

I want a query to look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE '03/01/2011' >= DateColumn
```

Where '03/01/2011' is a variable I'm passing in.

I tried:

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(2011, 3, 1);
QueryOver.Of<Table>(() => tAlias).Where(() => myDate >= tAlias.DateColumn)
```

However, this throws the following exception:

> Could not find property myDate

Any ideas how to do this using a QueryOver expression?

Comment: NHibernate QueryOver always assumes the Column is on the left and the value is on the right of the expression. So the exception message is saying "NHibernate assumed the column was myDate, but can't find any mapping for myDate".

Comment: I was wondering about that Philll, thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never tried using Where with an parameterless expression, what if you tried something like this (what I'd use if I were doing a QueryOver[Table], not sure if there is a difference with .Of[Table])?

```
.Where(r => r.DateColumn <= myDate)
```

All the examples I've seen use the constant on the right side of the expression too, not sure if there's anything to that (**edit:** looking at Phill's comment above, it appears that NHibernate does expect the column on the left and the value on the right).

Comment: Somehow I convinced myself that this would product different results, but I can't prove otherwise.  Thanks for talking some sense to me. =)